# How CORS security bypassed?

Tags: security, browser, cors

Server does not send any CORS headers therefore I assume that browser should block request sent to different domain, but it does not happen. My browser has all the default settings. I wonder how people bypass CORS security in this case?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a page from bb.b.com is requesting a resource from bb.b.com - no CORS involved.

Comment: Request was made from aa.a.com.

Comment: The `Referer` header says otherwise.

Comment: You are right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As peeebeee mentioned request was made from `bb.b.com`. Whole page is put in `<frame src="http://bb.b.com">` element.